# How to group values by hour in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with values for every 10 minutes.

```
date_time                  value
...................................
2018-05-20 12:00:00        3.775
2018-05-20 12:10:00        3.733
2018-05-20 12:20:00        3.754
2018-05-20 12:30:00        3.775
2018-05-20 12:40:00        3.766
2018-05-20 12:50:00        3.758
2018-05-20 13:00:00        3.654
2018-05-20 13:10:00        3.812
2018-05-20 13:20:00        3.804         
...                        ...
```

I am trying to create a query that will group these values by hour so that I can get the average. So for each line of results, I would have an average of 6 values.

Each hour would have the average of the last 6 values (current hour included). Example :
13:00 would be the average of 12:10, 12:20, 12:30, 12:40, 12:50 and 13:00.
14:00 the average of 13:10, 13:20, 13:30, 13:40, 13:50 and 14:00.
...

I tried many ways but could not get this done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        DATE(date_time) , 
        ' ' ,
        HOUR(date_time) + CEILING(MINUTE(date_time) / 60),
        ':00'
    ) AS hours,
    AVG(value) AS avg_value
FROM table_name
GROUP BY 
    DATE(date_time), 
    HOUR(date_time) + CEILING(MINUTE(date_time) / 60);
```

For [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e72af7/21)

```
hours               avg_value
2018-05-20 12:00    3775
2018-05-20 13:00    3740
2018-05-20 14:00    3808
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` with appropriate timestamp functions

```
 select date(date_time), hour(date_time), avg(value)
 from your_table
 group by date(date_time), hour(date_time)
```